# Applying Terraform On Two Different AWS Accounts In the Same Plan

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-route53

We're currently porting some of our CloudFormation templates to Terraform.  In one of these templates we use a custom resource with a Lambda function.

The purpose of the function is to assume a role in our main AWS account; where R53 DNS is managed, and add a newly generated CloudFront dns there.

I am wondering if there's a way to do this in terraform, such that:

1. create the cloudfront resource, alb, etc on the dev/qa/prod accounts
2. add the r53 recordset to the main account

All within the same terraform plan.  Can I choose an IAM role when creating a resource? Or choose the account where the resource should be created?

The only reference I have found is [here](https://hackernoon.com/terraform-with-aws-assume-role-21567505ea98)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploying to multiple AWS accounts with Terraform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52206436/deploying-to-multiple-aws-accounts-with-terraform)

Comment: @ydaetskcoR that's true! Although stackoverflow didnt return that in my search

Comment: Yep, nor mine. Had to Google it :(

Answer (score 4):

You can configure [multiple providers](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html#alias-multiple-provider-instances) ( one per account in your case) and create an alias for each. Then you will need to specify the provider for each ressource. Example:

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "eu-west-1"
  profile = "profile1"
  alias   = "account1"
}

provider "aws" {
  region  = "eu-west-1"
  profile = "profile2"
  alias   = "account2"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "function1" {
  provider = "aws.account1" // will be created in account 1
  ...
}
resource "aws_lambda_function" "function2" {
  provider = "aws.account2" // will be created in account 2
  ...
}
```