# How to obtain AWS certificate from different region in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to deploy AWS CloudFront distribution in `eu-central-1` that will have a custom certificate set. Here's the relevant code excerpt:

```
data "aws_acm_certificate" "my_cert" {
  domain   = "*.example.com"
  statuses = ["ISSUED"]
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "static_content" {
  origin {
    domain_name = aws_s3_bucket.test.bucket_domain_name
    origin_id   = local.s3_origin_id
  }

  viewer_certificate {
    acm_certificate_arn = data.aws_acm_certificate.my_cert.arn
  }

  ...
}
```

The terraform [doc says](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudfront_distribution.html#viewer-certificate-arguments):

> `acm_certificate_arn` - The ARN of the AWS Certificate Manager certificate that you wish to use with this distribution. Specify this, cloudfront_default_certificate, or iam_certificate_id. **The ACM certificate must be in US-EAST-1**.

In the AWS Console I can see the certificate ARN contains `us-east-1` in it. But when I debug the `data.aws_acm_certificate.my_cert` the ARN contains `eu-central-1`.

Is there a way how to get the ARN of the `us-east-1` cert while deploying CloudFront anywhere else?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/52206826/2291321 answer your question?

Comment: Oh yeah! That's it ;)